# Any example of spring cloud stream multi binder using kafka streams as input channel and rabbitmq as output?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

We have a requirement to consume data through kafka streams and send the output to rabbitmq channel. Is there an example available available similar to this ?

I tried this - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multibinder-samples/multibinder-kafka-rabbit/src/main/resources/application.yml

spring.cloud.stream.default-binder: kafka

but getting this - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The binder 'kafka' cannot bind a com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some current limitations for mixing two different binding target types(`KStream` and `MessageChannel` in the same processor (`StreamListener`)). As a work around, you can have two `StreamListener` methods in the same application. One is the normal Kafka Streams processor in which you have an input `KStream` and an output `KStream`. The second `StreamListener` method is a multi binder scenario in which you are receiving from the Kafka topic and output to the Rabbit exchange. I think this should address the use case that you are describing above. Let us know if that works. We can add a sample application demonstrating this.

Comment: Here is a sample that shows how to do this: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-to-rabbitmq-message-channel